# Trying to get property of non-object error help please

Tags: php

```
<div class="manga-created pull-right">
    <i class="fa fa-user"></i>
    <small><?php echo $manga->user->username; ?>,</small>
    <i class="fa fa-calendar-o"></i>
    <small><?php echo App::make("HelperController")->formateCreationDate($manga->created_at); ?></small>
</div>
```

This line here is where am getting the error at:

```
<small><?php echo $manga->user->username; ?>,</small>
```

Comment: what is `$manga`? can you provide a vardump?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it looks like one of `$manga` or `$manga->user` is not an object. So it should be like one of these:

```
<?php echo $manga->user['username']; ?>
```

or

```
<?php echo $manga['user']->username; ?>
```

Comment: thank you. `<?php echo $manga->user['username']; ?>` did the trick.

Comment: @user5819198 Pls accept the answer so that others know the issue is resolved.